# Function invocation from triggers are currently not supported

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce-functions

1)**When I Try to call the Function in the Synchronous way in the apex trigger I am getting below Error "Function invocation from triggers are currently not supported"**

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class FunctionTest {
    Public static void deletefunc(String acc){
        functions.Function myFunction = functions.Function.get('MyFunctionProject.deleteopportunity');
        functions.FunctionInvocation invocation = myFunction.invoke(acc);
        String jsonResponse = invocation.getResponse();
        System.debug('Response from deletefunc ' + jsonResponse);
        }
    }
```

Function:

```
module.exports = async function (event, context, logger) {
logger.info(`Invoking Deleteopportunity with payload ${JSON.stringify(event.data || {})}`);
const payload = event.data;
const Opportunity = await context.org.dataApi.query(`SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity where AccountId='${payload}'`);
logger.info(JSON.stringify(Opportunity));
const uow = context.org.dataApi.newUnitOfWork();
for(const element of Opportunity.records){
        uow.registerDelete({
          type: "Opportunity",
          fields: {
               id : element.fields.id
          }
        });
}
try{
    const response = await context.org.dataApi.commitUnitOfWork(uow);
    return response;
}catch(e){
     logger.error(e.message);
     return e.message;
   }
}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger accounttrigger on Account (after insert,after update){
List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
for(Account eachAccount : Trigger.New){
    accountIds.add(eachAccount.Id);
}
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
    if(accountIds.size()>0){
        FunctionTest.deletefunc(JSON.serialize(accountIds));
    }
  }
}
```

2)**For the Single Project how many function can we create is there is Limit or best practice stand point we should limit the number of function for the project?**

Answer (score 3):

I can't see it explicitly in the Functions doc, but from an Apex point of view, you're not allowed to do any synchronous callout from a Trigger.

So I assume the limit is the same for Functions. A synchronous Function can wait for up to 2mn for the response, and obviously you don't want to hold the save transaction for that time (imagine an end user clicking on the save button and looking at the spinner for 2mn).

If you want to call a Function from an Apex Trigger, you should call it asynchronously, providing a callback method:

```
Function.invoke(payload, callback)
```

The related documentation can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/invoke.html?q=limits#use-asynchronous-invocation).

I don't know if there is a limit for the number of functions, limits are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/limits.html) but there is nothing about this topic. I guess the limits are more on execution time, process memory, payload and response size, than on the number of Functions you create.

You can try asking this specific question in the [Trailblazer Community related Chatter Group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000GyR0SAK), where Salesforce Functions Product Managers may be able to give you the official answer.

Comment: This is correct. A synchronous function invoke acts like a callout from a limit perspective. Use the async invoke model if you need to call a function from a trigger. We do not allow holding open a database transaction while a callout is happening since it causes massive issues with record locks (and also some really ugly perf issues if done wrong).

There is not a finite daily limit on async invoke/callbacks - it explicitly does not count against the daily async apex job limit (but normal "based on resource availability" applies like it does to other async apex).